How can I read parameters from a script in VSCode powershell
I want to achieve something like this:
npm run build

sets environment variable BACKEND_URL to a default value of 'http://localhost:8080'
and
npm run build myCustomURL

to set environment variable BACKEND_URL = 'myCustomURL'
The script I am using
 "build": "tsc -b && vite build --env BACKEND_URL=${0:-http://localhost:8080}"
I read that this is how you pass the arguments in a script and that is not really working in my case, tried with 1 instead of 0 too, but still nothing.
This is how my vite.config.ts file looks like
This is how my package.json looks like (1st pic)
Part 2 of package.json

can you also attach a screenshot of your package.json. You have given us very little information

Hello, I just edited it, sorry for the lack of information!

Inside your package.json, go to script and add the following:
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build --env BACKEND_URL=${0:-http://localhost:8080}"
  }
}```

and in vite configuration use: ```export default defineConfig({
plugins: [react()],
define: {
'process.env.BACKEND_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.BACKEND_URL || 'http://localhost:8080'),
},
});


instead of screenshots, attach your file or part of the file as a text format for better question quality

@IdrisSelimi It did not solve my problem sadly... when I run "npm run build" my environment variable still stays the same as before and doesn't change to http://localhost:8080

try running ```scripts": {
"build": "BACKEND_URL=${npm_config_backend_url:-http://localhost:8080} vite build"
}


script fails now

what is the error?

'BACKEND_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command

By the error I understand that you are on a windows os. Windows does not natively support settings environments as unix systems. To resolve this problem I suggest you install cross-env package.
npm install cross-env --save-dev
After that you will need to modify the scripts to ```{
"scripts": {
"build": "cross-env BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8080 vite build",
"build:custom": "cross-env BACKEND_URL=$npm_config_backend_url vite build"
}
}


Yes I am on windows. I saw the cross-env solution earlier but I wanted to make it without it, but seems impossible? Anyway, thanks a lot!

no problem, if I was helpful please upvote my answer.

I do not have it unlocked .....
